# Error in module (veins::obstaclecontrol)

Tags: xml, config, omnet++, veins

I defined a simple map in sumo with 5 edges and inserted it in my veins but I get this error

> error in module (veins::obstaclecontrol) rsuexamplesenario.obstacles
>   (id=2) at event #467, t=46:unable to use simpleObstacleShadowing: no
>   obstacles have been added.

I don't know how to remove obstacles from config.xml and omnetpp.ini file in veins.

Comment: *.obstacles.debug = false
*.obstacles.obstacles = xmldoc("config.xml", "//AnalogueModel[@type='SimpleObstacleShadowing']/obstacles")
comment these in ini file and comment these in config file
<AnalogueModel type="SimpleObstacleShadowing">
   <parameter name="carrierFrequency" type="double" value="5.890e+9"/>
   <obstacles>
    <type id="building" db-per-cut="9" db-per-meter="0.4" />
   </obstacles>
  </AnalogueModel>

Answer (score 4):

Comment out these lines in the ini file:

```
*.obstacles.debug = false
*.obstacles.obstacles = xmldoc("config.xml", "//AnalogueModel[@type='SimpleObstacleShadowing']/obstacles"‌​)
```

Comment out these lines in the config file:

```
<AnalogueModel type="SimpleObstacleShadowing">
   <parameter name="carrierFrequency" type="double" value="5.890e+9"/>
   <obstacles>
      <type id="building" db-per-cut="9" db-per-meter="0.4" />
   </obstacles>
</AnalogueModel>
```